# I am getting error in graphql while making query for specific id

Tags: mongodb, graphql

schema:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id : { type: GraphQLID },
        name : { type: GraphQLString },
        email : { type: GraphQLString },
    })
})


const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                id: { type: GraphQLID }
            },
            resolve(parent, args){
                return User.findById(args.id);
            }
        }
    }
})

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery
});
```

Here i am fetching data by id from mongodb.

I am using mongoose for mongodb client.
I have setup server with express and graphql.

and  i am making below query to get result by specifi id

```
{
    user(id: 2){
        name
    }
}
```

But, i am getting below error while making query.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"2\" at path \"_id\" for model \"User\"",
        "locations": [
            {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3
            }
        ],
        "path": [
            "user"
        ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "user": null
    }
}
```

my id in database is just a integer value like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d49c6dc54f1cec013ee6b49"),
    "id" : 10,
    "name" : "Clementina DuBuque",
    "email" : "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",                
}
```

Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

`type: UserType` this should be `type: new GraphQLList(UserType),`